# Unrecognized selector error.

Tags: ios, uiview, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to send a UIColor to a subclass of UIView. I am getting an unrecognized selector error.

```
-[Subclass fillView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2006f880
```

(Subclass is a class in my project, but I have no clue how it is related to fillView.

Here is the line that causes the issue.

```
view.fillView.fillColor = fillColor;
```

The subclass has a property that is used in the drawRect method

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *fillColor;

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _fillColor.CGColor);
```

Comment: What is fillView?  Why are you trying to use it?

Comment: Are you using arc? If so, make sure you are keeping a reference to the view. I once had a problem similar to this, and making the viewController a @property did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
view.fillView.fillColor = fillColor;
```

is equivalent to

```
[[view fillView] setFillColor:fillColor];
```

so whatever class "view" is (it appears to be of class 'Subclass'), it does not respond to the method fillView.  The error has got nothing to do with fillColor.  Your code is crashing before it gets to the setFillColor call.

Comment: This was correct. I was getting the view from an array, and accidentally trying to assign to an object of the wrong class that happened to be in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case view.fillView.fillColor will not work.
If you really want to set a color as background of your view, try this

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Hope this will help.